# JavaFX: Having issues making a draggable node

Tags: java, javafx

I'm attempting to make a node that I've created draggable.

I'm able to place the nodes at the point that I like in the pane, but when it comes to dragging them around, they just seem to be automatically offput.

I've tried making a Delta class that would just contain an x and y which would be updated accordingly during the pressing of the mouse on the node.

```
nfaPane.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            if (!event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) return;
            for (final NFANode node : nfaNodes)
                if (node.isHover())
                    return;
            final NFANode nfaNode = new NFANode(nfaNodes.size(), event.getX(), event.getY());
            nfaPane.getChildren().add(nfaNode);
            nfaNodes.add(nfaNode);
            Delta dragDelta = new Delta();
            nfaNode.setOnMousePressed(event1 -> {
                dragDelta.setDragDeltaX(nfaNode.getLayoutX());
                dragDelta.setDragDeltaY(nfaNode.getLayoutY());
            });

            nfaNode.setOnMouseDragged(event1 -> {
                nfaNode.moveTo(event1.getSceneX() + dragDelta.getDragDeltaX(), event1.getSceneY() + dragDelta.getDragDeltaY());
            });
        });
```

The node itself is defined by the class NFANode:

```
package sample;

import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

/**
 * Created by David on 11/5/2016.
 */
public class NFANode extends Group {
    //private List<NFANode> next;
    public static final Font nfaFont = Font.font("Footlight MT Light", 25);
    private final Ellipse bubble;
    private final Text text;
    private double textWidth;

    public NFANode(int value, double x, double y) {
        this.text = new Text(x, y + 5, "");
        renumber(value);
        this.text.setFont(nfaFont);
        textWidth = this.text.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
        bubble = new Ellipse(x, y, this.text.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() + 5, 25);
        this.text.setX(x - textWidth / 2);
        bubble.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        bubble.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        getChildren().addAll(bubble, this.text);
    }

    public Text getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void renumber(final int value) {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : String.valueOf(value).toCharArray()) builder.append((char) (c + 8272));
        text.setText("Q" + builder.toString());
    }

    public void moveTo(final double x, final double y) {
        bubble.setCenterX(x);
        bubble.setCenterY(y);
        text.setX(x - textWidth / 2);
        text.setY(y + 5);
    }
}
```

I'm confused as to why this would affect the position of the node when dragged?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to take the mouse position into account when it's pressed.

You've got the following equation

```
mousePosition - mousePressedPosition = targetPosition - startPosition
```

so `dragDelta` should be

```
startPosition - mousePressedPosition = targetPosition - mousePosition
```

Personally I prefer using the coordinate system of the parent, but using scene coordinates should work too, unless you've got some transformations in place, that are not just translations.

**Example**

```
private static class Delta {

    private double dragDeltaX;
    private double dragDeltaY;

    public double getDragDeltaX() {
        return dragDeltaX;
    }

    public double getDragDeltaY() {
        return dragDeltaY;
    }

    public void setDragDelta(double x, double y) {
        this.dragDeltaX = x;
        this.dragDeltaY = y;
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Circle c = new Circle(30);
    c.setLayoutX(50);
    c.setLayoutY(50);

    Pane root = new Pane(c);

    Delta dragDelta = new Delta();

    c.setOnMousePressed(event1 -> {
        Point2D mouseInParent = c.localToParent(event1.getX(), event1.getY());
        dragDelta.setDragDelta(c.getLayoutX() - mouseInParent.getX(), c.getLayoutY()-mouseInParent.getY());
        event1.consume();
    });

    c.setOnMouseDragged(event1 -> {
        Point2D mouseInParent = c.localToParent(event1.getX(), event1.getY());
        c.setLayoutX(mouseInParent.getX() + dragDelta.getDragDeltaX());
        c.setLayoutY(mouseInParent.getY() + dragDelta.getDragDeltaY());
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```